# how to pass column name as parameter in psycopg2?

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

using python3.4.3, psycopg2 is installed through pip

```
col = 'concept'
cur.execute("select  regexp_split_to_array( %s ,'；') from MyTable limit 200",(col,))
```

gives me result like this:

`(['concept'],)`

My suggestion is that `psycopg2` generate sql query like following:

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY('concept','；')
FROM
    MyTable
LIMIT 200
```

So I changed the code a little,

```
cur.execute("select  regexp_split_to_array(" + col + " ,'；') from MyTable limit 200")
```

It works, but string concat is UGLY and often dangerous in sql. Is there better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you are more or less bound to create such a SQL string yourself, though there are probably prettier ways to do it that using string concatenation.

You are correct that allowing unverified user inputs as parts of SQL queries can be dangerous (search for "SQL injection" to find the ugly details). While data values can be inserted into your SQL using what are often referred to as ["parameterized queries"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), unfortunately this technique cannot be used with column names. The reasons for this are somewhat complex - parameterization is used to prepare an optimized version of the statement for executing, and allowing variable column names would invalidate the optimizations.

You could, however, use either of Python's string formatting techniques to create the statement, either of which would be prettier than concatenation.

```
"select regexp_split_to_array(%s ,'；') from MyTable limit 200" % col
```

and

```
"select regexp_split_to_array({} ,'；') from MyTable limit 200".format(col)
```

will both create the statement you need.